# Installed GNU grep on OSX, but can't use

Tags: path, homebrew

I've tried installing GNU grep on OSX, and it seems to be installed, but I can't use it.. I've done so using homebrew, Macports is having some issues currently, so I can't use that.

To install: `brew tap homebrew/dupes; brew install grep`

Which returns: `Warning: homebrew/dupes already tapped! Warning: homebrew/dupes/grep-2.21 already installed`

Symlinking seems to work to /usr/local/bin/ggrep. When I add the alias `alias grep="ggrep"` and do `grep --version`, I get `-bash: ggrep: command not found`. Which is true, since there is no ggrep in the folder. I've tried installing with and without `--with-default-names`.

The folder `/usr/local/Cellar/grep/2.21/bin/` contains the following:

```
-r-xr-xr-x 1 Wes admin 158 Oct 14 09:27 egrep
-r-xr-xr-x 1 Wes admin 158 Oct 14 09:27 fgrep
```

Which is strange to me, since the documentation implies that `The command has been installed with the prefix "g".`

I've seen the following post, but none of the solutions work for me. [Updating grep for Mac OS 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352197/updating-grep-for-mac-os-10-7/26064330#26064330)

Does anyone have any solutions? I really want to use GNU grep.

Output of `brew unlink grep && brew link grep -v`:

```
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/grep/2.21...
6 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/grep/2.21...
ln -s ../Cellar/grep/2.21/bin/egrep egrep
ln -s ../Cellar/grep/2.21/bin/fgrep fgrep
ln -s ../../Cellar/grep/2.21/share/info/grep.info grep.info info /usr/local/share/info/grep.info
ln -s ../../../Cellar/grep/2.21/share/man/man1/egrep.1 egrep.1
ln -s ../../../Cellar/grep/2.21/share/man/man1/fgrep.1 fgrep.1
ln -s ../../../Cellar/grep/2.21/share/man/man1/grep.1 grep.1
6 symlinks created`
```

**New:**
`brew uninstall grep; brew install grep`

```
$ which -a grep
/usr/bin/grep

$ which -a ggrep
/usr/local/bin/ggrep

$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

This time, it seems something is different. `ggrep` is finally installed! I think the `unlink`/`link` straightened some things out.
How can I set `ggrep` as the default? With `alias`?

Comment: what is the output of `brew unlink grep && brew link grep -v`?

Comment: Are you aware of the `$PATH` environment variable?

Comment: What you can do to make it easier for us to help you: 1) install grep without default names 2) add the output of `which -a grep` and `which -a ggrep`. 3) add the output of `echo $PATH`. Besides, it's best to edit a question to add more information. Additional information in comments is very messy.

Comment: You call for trouble if you use MacPorts and homebrew simultaneously. Your `$PATH` is obviously messed up, as other already pointed out.

Comment: I haven't used Macports, I tried installing it, but the repo's aren't loading. This had to do with a bug they were facing. Anyways, I've added new info to my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update: as pointed out in the comments, this option has been removed in 2019. Nowadays Homebrew installs prefixed binaries in its standard path, and non-prefixed ones in a separate one. In order to have the non-prefixed binaries available, you have to add that separate path into your `PATH` environment variable:

```bash
PATH="$(brew --prefix grep)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Add the above in your `~/.bashrc` (for Bash) or `~/.zshrc` (for Zsh). By using `brew --prefix grep` instead of a hardcoded `/usr/local/opt/grep` you ensure this works everywhere, including on machines where Homebrew is not installed under `/usr/local`.

---

Original answer:

To make GNU grep the default install it with `--with-default-names`:

```
$ brew install grep --with-default-names
```

If you already have it installed use `reinstall` instead of `install`.

Ensure that `/usr/local/bin` (the location of GNU grep) is *before* `/usr/bin` (the location of the BSD grep) in your `$PATH`; which seems to be the case here.

You might have to start a new shell session afterward because Bash caches the binaries paths for the current session. This means that the first time you use `grep` it’ll determine which binary it’ll use depending on your `$PATH` and cache it. The next time it’ll use the cached value so changing your `$PATH` won’t change anything until you reload the shell.

Comment: `--with-default-names` is no longer available, see: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/why-was-with-default-names-removed/4405/3

Comment: Error: invalid option: --with-default-names

Comment: Thanks; somehow I missed the comment from 2019.

Answer (score 9):

Offically out of date for the answer above.

As of Homebrew version 2.0.0 the `--with-default-names` flag is no longer available.

from the official documentation

> --with-default-names is no longer supported. It is now installed into its own directory and you will need to adjust your PATH to use it.

What you need to do is to add this command to your shell

```sh
PATH="/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Sept. 6th, 2023 the path has changed again. Per https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/grep:

> All commands have been installed with the prefix "g".
> If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you
> can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
> `PATH="$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

So one could simply use `ggrep` or add it to their shell's PATH variable with:

**Fish shell**

1. `grep --version`
2. `edit ~/.config/fish/config.fish`
3. Add `set --global --export PATH $HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin $PATH` and save
4. `source ~/.config/fish/config.fish`
5. `grep --version`

**Z shell**

1. `grep --version`
2. `edit ~/.zshrc`
3. Add `PATH="$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` and save
4. `source ~/.zshrc`
5. `grep --version`

**Bash shell**

1. `grep --version`
2. `edit ~/.bashrc`
3. Add `PATH="$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` and save
4. `source ~/.bashrc`
5. `grep --version`

If these instructions stop working, go to https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/grep and read the updates and then come back here and update this answer.

Comment: The path has been the same since [the removal of `--with-default-names`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/43f2e19d93f04eddf24ec19187b3648f594b80e2).